# Least squares convolution

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, least-squares

I'm detecting features in an image by computing the least-squares error between the filter and a region of the image. This approach is identical to convoluting the filter with the image, but instead of computing the convolution $\int f(\tau) g(t - \tau) dt$, I'm computing the least squares error $\int (f(\tau)-g(t - \tau))^2 dt$.

Question 1:
What is this technique called?

Question 2:
Can it be computed in frequency domain?
I would like to speed-up this algorithm by transforming both image and filter to frequency domain using FFT and computing the least squares error in frequency domain.

The Laplace transform of the convolution operator is a simple multiplication in frequency domain.
$$\mathcal{L}\biggl\{\int f(\tau) g(t - \tau) dt\biggr\} = F(s) \cdot G(s)$$
What is the Laplace transform of least squares?
$$\mathcal{L}\biggl\{\int (f(\tau)-g(t - \tau))^2 dt\biggr\} = \, ?$$

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't find a solution to either of the posted questions.